# Can someone help me with rectifying the output of this "Prime Numbers below 100" code?

Tags: c++

**This Question has been answered**
So basically, I just wrote down a code to display all the prime numbers below 100. This is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
       int n=2,i;
       cout<<"All Prime numbers below 100 are : \n";

       while(n<=100)
       {
           for(i=2; i<n/2; i++)
           {
              if (n%i==0)
              {
                 goto restart;
              }

              else
              {
                 cout<<n<<"\t";
              }    
          }
          restart:
          n++;
      }
      return 0;
   }
```

But instead of the output being 2 3 5 7 11 .....  it comes out as:

```
All prime numbers below 100 are:

7  9  11  11  11  13  13  13  13  15  15  and so on ...
```

I just want the output to display all prime numbers starting from 2 to 97 without repetitions. thank you.

/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/--/-/-/-/-

I got out of the problem with a slight modification.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n=2, i;
    while(n<=100)
    {
        for(i=2; i<=n/2; i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
            {
                goto label;
            }
        }
        cout<<n<<", ";
        label:
            n++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Thank you to everyone for your valuable time.** (And the reason why I use such beginner type codes is I've just started out on C++ like a week ago. I have so much more codes (like bool, isPrime, etc.) to learn.)

Keeping Cranking 'em codes, fellow coders :D

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of using a `goto`, you can just use `break` for the same effect.

Comment: Do you know what a prime number is? Your program outputs all the numbers greater than 5 that aren't divisible by 2 right now

Comment: You could use the Sieve of Eratosthenes

Comment: Your algorithm has other problems than just not printing the 2 and 5. it repeats numbers, like 11.

Comment: Also, your algorithm is correct, but your code to output the prime numbers isn't. If you print out `n` in your if statement, notice that it will print out all numbers that are _not_ prime. Keep track of these numbers and print out all of those that are not part of this list at the end.

Comment: Just a helpful note, avoid using `goto` as much as possible.

Comment: @sushibossftw I've seen quite a number of examples of people avoiding `goto` *by all means* - finally resulting in much more complex code... The accepted answer is an example for (well, perhaps yet somewhere in the border area, but still). So I'd formulate it a bit weaker: Avoid `goto`, if the alternative you have does not introduce additional complexity (I'd classify the answer proposing a separate function as such: Sure, we have another function, but that test on its own is meaningful and might be reused somewhere else in the future).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is OK but has two critical errors. Firstly, you output `n` for each modulo you check. You should only output `n` if all the modulo checks fail. Also, your boundary condition isn't quite right - it should be `<=`. Working code with minimal changes would be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n=2,i;
    cout<<"All Prime numbers below 100 are : \n";

    while(n<=100)
    {
        for(i=2; i<=n/2; i++)
        {
            if (n%i==0)
            {
                goto restart;
            }
        }

        cout<<n<<"\t";

        restart:
        n++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you wanted to make slightly cleaner code then dont use `goto`, use a double `for` loop and a `break`. Also your boundary condition for `i` should be `i*i<=n` as thats a tighter bound. So something like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cout<<"All Prime numbers below 100 are : \n";

    for(int n=2; n<100; ++n)
    {
        bool isPrime = true;
        for(int i=2; i*i<=n; i++)
        {
            if (n%i==0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isPrime)
            std::cout<<n<<"\t";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I am an absolute beginner and I have so much more codes to learn like the bool, isPrime and so on. But I got away with the problem with a little modification :

Comment: The double for loop *is* cleaner - I don't agree on avoiding the goto: You need to add an additional variable, initialise it correctly, then re-assign before the break, and after the loop, you need an additional test for. Admitted, not much of an effort, but the `goto` approach appears simpler and cleaner to me in given case...

Comment: Just for completeness: `i <= n` is only an issue for `n ∈ [2;4]`, for any other value, `n/2 > sqrt(n)` and we'd be fine with `i < n` as well...

Answer (score 3):

There is an obvious error in your algorithm. You might be able to find it using a debugger, but I think that a better way would be for you to learn about extracting a function. What you want your main function to do, is exactly: `if n is prime: output n`. So you should write it that way:

```
int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    if (is_prime(i))
      std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Of course for that to work you'll need to define the function `is_prime`:

```
bool is_prime (int n) {
  for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; ++i)
    if (n % i == 0) 
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Note also that there is no need to check if `n` is divisible by numbers greater then it's square root. If there are no divisors up to the square root, the next possible divisor is `n` itself.

As others mentioned, that's not the optimal algorithm to solve this problem, but for small values it's definetely good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check if each number is prime. Therefor you have to check if it is dividable by a smaller number.

A more efficient way to find all prime numbers up to a maximal number is the Sieve of Erathosthenes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const unsigned int maxNum(100);
    std::vector<bool> prime(maxNum, true);
    for (unsigned int i(2); i*i < maxNum; ++i) {
        if (!prime[i]) continue;
        for (unsigned int j(2*i); j < maxNum; j += i) {
            prime[j] = false;
        }
    }
    for (unsigned int i(2); i < maxNum; ++i) {
        if (prime[i]) std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A list of all numbers is created. Each multiple of of each number is removed from this list.

Comment: `i*i <= maxnum` should be fine here, too. I'd prefer: `for(j = i+i; j < maxnum; j += i)`, you spare the multiplications that way. There's no reason to use `at`, index operator is more efficient, you won't be exceeding valid range anyway.

Comment: And you only need to run the inner loop if `prime[i]` has not yet already been set to false...

Comment: @Aconcagua i fixed it